# What is this ColdFusion evaluation actually doing?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm reviewing some code inside of a cfmodule it got me scratching my head.

The cfmodule is being called like:

```
<cfmodule template="/cfmods/mod1.cfm" mode="breadcrumbs">
```

and the code inside has a series of cfelse statements but this one is the one that gave me pause.

```
<cfelseif isdefined("attributes.mode") 
AND NOT comparenocase("breadcrumbs", attributes.mode)>
```

Can someone translate this into spoken words?  I know [CompareNoCase](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_07.html) will return a negative number, 0, or a positive number as a result.  So what does adding the the word `not` do, check for the opposite of what was returned from CompareNoCase?

Comment: It is a convoluted way of saying "if the two strings are equal" (ignoring case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AND** (CONDITION) checks if the condition is **TRUE**.
**AND NOT** (CONDITION) checks if the condition is **FALSE**.

So that statement is saying:

If Attributes.Mode exists as a variable and attributes.mode IS EQUAL to Breadcrumbs regardless of case, THEN...

Comment: regarding the CONTINUE, is that CONTINUE **within** the code in the CFELSEIF block of code or does it move on to the **next** cfelseif block?

Comment: I believe @BKK meant THEN, instead of CONTINUE.

Comment: *attributes.mode IS NOT EQUAL to Breadcrumbs* Disclaimer: I am majorly sleep deprived, so take this with a grain of salt, but ... I think that is backwards. `compareNoCase()` returns `0` when the two strings are equal. CF treats the number `0` as `false`. Adding a `NOT` just reverses the meaning to make it: ie "When the two strings **are equal**, regardless of case".

Comment: I wanted to ask a follow up question to your comment after my question but couldn't put it into words where I thought it made sense.  Thanks for expanding on your comment just above and answering what it was that I was unable to ask.